# How to return result in doInBackground after login API completion block is finished in UserLoginTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kotlin

I used default LoginActivity in Android Studio and created a simple login view. In my app, the authentication task and access token generation is done by the server via API call. However, since the api call must have a completion block, my login function in `doInBackground` also does. Therefore the authentication result exists in the thread of the completion block, which makes the returned result of the original `doInBackground` to `onPostExecute` incorrect. The functions are overriden, so I cannot change their parameters and formats. I'm still new in android developing and still not very familiar with its asynchronized task, so I would like to ask if there is any way to halt in `doInBackground` and wait for the result in the completion block? Or is there any better solution to solve my API login? Thanks.

Here the code of my UserLoginTask (written in kotlin but I think the concept would be the same with java):

```
inner class UserLoginTask internal constructor(private val mUsername: String, private val mPassword) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Boolean? {
        var result = false
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000)
        } catch(e: InterruptedException) {
            return false
        }

        MyLoginService().login(mUsername, mPassword, onCompleted = { token ->
            // I want to get the login result from here and return it to onPostExecute
            // It's no use if I change the result to true here because the result is already returned before completion.
        })

        return result
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(success: Boolean?) {
        mAuthTask = null
        showProgress(false)
        if(success!!) {
            finish()
        } else {
            mPasswordView!!.error = getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password)
            mPasswordView!!.requestFocus()
        }

    }

    override fun onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null
        showProgress(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Parameters and return type of async task overrided functions are depends upon parameter defined in AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>().
So change the third parameter Boolean to what you want in onpostExecute method.

Comment: You are returning "result" to postExecute..From this code the "result" is always false.. You are never changing it's value ?

Comment: Thanks @AshimKansal for telling me how to change the return type, helps a lot! Now I could try to focus on dealing with completion block  only...

Comment: To, @sunilsunny Yes, the result value is not changed, and actually it's no use to change it after getting the authentication result in the completion block, which runs in different place.

Comment: MyLoginService().login is already an asynchronious call, so not need to call in in onBackground

Comment: That's it! Finally I moved MyLoginService().login on main thread and discarded the default generated UserLoginTask, it works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that but it's not a good idea. In your case it's better to use something like Rx or futures and not an `AsyncTask`.

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Boolean? {
  val exchanger = Exchanger<Boolean>()
  MyLoginService().login(mUsername, mPassword, onCompleted = { token ->
    exchanger.exchange(token != null)
  })

  return try {
    exchanger.exchange(false)
  } catch (exception: InterruptedException) {
    false
  }
}
```

Comment: Finally I moved my login service to the main thread and solved the problem. However the exchanger you mentioned seems to be an useful tool! Learned something new, thanks!